# How to copy an array of strings into an object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings and an object:

```
const arr = ['abc', 'def'];

const obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 42,
};
```

I need to add the values in `arr` as keys in `obj`, so that the resulting object will look like:

```
const result = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 42,
  abc: true,
  def: true,
};
```

This is what I tried:

```
{ ...obj, ...arr.map(x => ({[x]: true })) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply use `Object.assign()` :

The below given example will mutate the original object :

```js
let arr = ['abc', 'def'];

let obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 42,
};

// Note it will mutate the original object
arr.forEach((e)=> Object.assign(obj, {[e] :true }));

console.log(obj);
```

In case you don`t want to mutate the original object try the following:

```js
let arr = ['abc', 'def'];

let obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 42,
};
let result =  Object.assign({}, obj);

arr.forEach((e)=> Object.assign(result, {[e] :true }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

This will mutate the `obj` and `result` will point to the `obj`. Meaning that changing one of them changes both.

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item] = true;
    return acc;
}, obj);
```

If you do not wish to mutate the `obj` then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item] = true;
    return acc;
}, { ...obj });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['abc', 'def'];

const obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 42,
};

const result = {...obj}; // don't modify the original obj

arr.forEach(i => result[i] = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a copy of the object and map the wanted properties.

```js
var array = ['abc', 'def'],
    object = { foo: true, bar: 42 },
    result = Object.assign({}, object, ...array.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Object.assign({}, obj, ...arr.map(x => ({[x]: true})))
```

---

Demo:

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def'];
const obj = {foo: true, bar: 42};

const result = Object.assign(obj, ...arr.map(x => ({[x]: true})));

console.log(result);
```